# Where is this additional data coming from when calling an object's attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my html I have:

```
<table class="customers" summary="User customers">
<%= @customers.each do |customer| %>
<tr>
<td class="customer"><%= customer.mobile %></td>
<td class="timestamp">Added <%= time_ago_in_words(customer.created_at) %> ago.</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

The first row of data reads:

```
#<Customer:0x103061018>#<Customer:0x10304c910>#<Customer:0x10304c7a8>#<Customer:0x10304c668>
```

Before the expected:

5234567894  Added 1 day ago.
5234567893  Added 1 day ago.
5234567892  Added 1 day ago.

What is that first row of data and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
<%= @customers.each do |customer| %>
```

try

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
```

(so without the equal sign).

The equal sign is telling Rails to print out the result of what is between the '<%' and '%>'.